# Zoomable image in markdown

Tags: image, github, zooming, markdown

I am embedding a large image on github wiki. But it turns to be unreadable due to its size.
Is it possible to make an image zoomable in markdown language? Specifically, on github wiki?

Thank you.

Comment: Would https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior help?

Comment: @VonC I am not sure if it is possible to run js within GitHub's markdown. Is it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simplest solution is to make a small version of the image (with GIMP/Photoshop etc.) and wrap it in a link to the original image.

```
[ ![](small.jpg) ](large.jpg)
```

Other solutions would require having custom CSS or JavaScript which you don't have on GitHub wikis etc.

Comment: no need for large, just duplicate it `[![](img.jpg)](img.jpg)`

Comment: @ctf0 thanks many for the tip. Easy way to make the image clickable and zoom in without fancy css/js/html

Comment: yes, but that forces the user to download the big image even if he doesn't click on the link. not optimal if you're, say, on a mobile network...

Comment: @mb21 u r right, but i think optimizing the image b4 uploading is the best all around.